# Why is my clear function not working?

Tags: javascript

```
function clear() {
document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = '';
document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = '';
document.getElementById("3").innerHTML = '';
}
<button onclick="clear()">Clear</button>
```

That is the function and my button that runs it.
The purpose of the function is to clear the paragraphs, but the button does nothing when I tested it out.

Why is this function not running when the button is clicked?

EDIT: sorry if the answer is obvious, i'm a beginner to JS
EDIT: HTML:

```
<p id="1"></p>
<p id="2"></p>
<p id="3"></p>
```

There is also a JS function that changes the text of the Paragraphs, but it doesn't loop

Comment: Show your HTML.

Comment: @Barmar the HTML I used for the button is under the JS. In my file the html is not actually under the JS

Comment: @Tler he's referring to the HTML you are attempting to "clear".

Comment: put `alert('YOOO');` as the first line in your `clear` function and try clicking the button again. Do you see an alert notification appear when you click?

Comment: Are you sure that button isn't submitting your "form" and reloading the page immediately after clearing it? Try to `return false` in the event handler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't name the function `clear` as the DOM has an old global method named [`clear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/clear). Try something else like clearMe

```js
function clearMe() {
  document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = '';
  document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = '';
  document.getElementById("3").innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<div id="1">
  foo
</div>
<div id="2">
  foo
</div>
<div id="3">
  foo
</div>
<button onclick="clearMe()">Clear</button>
```

Comment: That's a `document` function, not a `window` one, so it shouldn't do any harm? Also I'm pretty sure the function declaration would override the global.

Comment: @Bergi check out the dupe I closed this for

Comment: Ah, inline attribute event handler scopes. Of course.